# How can I put subclasses from the same baseclass into a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, subclass

How can I put subclasses from the same baseclass into a list?

I´m working with ASP.NET MVC3 and have created a basemodel-class with properties like name, age and so on. Now i have created submodels (subclasses) with more details. 
To easily handle the subclasses i want a list with the objects in it but how?

I have read about interfaces or ICollection and so on but don´t know what´s the right choice and how to start :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the list so it's of the base class:

```
List<BaseClass> myList = new List<BaseClass>();
```

then add your subclass objects as normal:

```
myList.Add(new SubClass1());
myList.Add(new SubClass2());
```

etc. where:

```
public class SubClass1 : BaseClass {}
public class SubClass2 : BaseClass {}
```

Then when you get them out you can use the `is` and `as` operators to determine what type they actually are and deal with them as appropriate.

Comment: Do you count the `is` and `as` operators as “Reflection”?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend

```
List<BaseClass>
```

for

```
class Derived1 : BaesClass {}
class Derived2 : BaesClass {}
```