# C# - list of subclass Types

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, types

I'd like to have a List of Class Types (not a list of Class instances) where each member of the List is a Subclass of MyClass.

For example, i can do this:

```
List<System.Type> myList;
myList.Add(typeof(mySubClass));
```

but i'd like to restrict the list to only accept subclasses of MyClass.

This is distinct from questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194482/how-can-i-put-subclasses-from-the-same-baseclass-into-a-list).
Ideally i'd like to avoid linq, as it's currently unused in my project.

Comment: Create you own list that inherits from List and override the `Add` method.

Comment: I don't think you can verify that at compile time.  You can create your own List and throw on Add though.

Comment: @dcg That wouldn't allow you to accomplish this at all, because `Add` isn't virtual.  You would need to compose a list, not inherit from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Servy is right in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958839/c-sharp-list-of-subclass-types/42959094#comment73012384_42958839), and [Lee in his](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958839/c-sharp-list-of-subclass-types/42959094#comment73012532_42959094): [it's much more preferable to compose than inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/3063273). So this is a good option:

```
public class ListOfTypes<T>
{
    private List<Type> _types = new List<Type>();
    public void Add<U>() where U : T
    {
        _types.Add(typeof(U));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new ListOfTypes<SuperClass>();
x.Add<MySubClass>()
```

Note that you can make this class implement an interface like [`IReadOnlyList<Type>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to give other code read access to the contained `Type`s without other code having to depend on this class.

But if you want to inherit anyway, you could create your own class that inherits from `List`, then add your own generic `Add` method like this:

```
public class ListOfTypes<T> : List<Type>
{
    public void Add<U>() where U : T
    {
        Add(typeof(U));
    }
}
```

Just be aware of [what Lee said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958839/c-sharp-list-of-subclass-types/42959094#comment73012532_42959094): with this second version you can still `Add(typeof(Foo))`.

Comment: I would avoid inheritance since you can also do `Add(typeof(string))`.

Answer (score 1):

You should derive a list class from List and override the Add method to perform the type checking that you need. I'm not aware of a way in .NET to do that automatically.

Something like this could work:

```
public class SubTypeList : List<System.Type>
{
    public System.Type BaseType { get; set; }

    public SubTypeList()
        : this(typeof(System.Object))
    {
    }

    public SubTypeList(System.Type baseType)
    {
        BaseType = BaseType;
    }

    public new void Add(System.Type item)
    {
        if (item.IsSubclassOf(BaseType) == true)
        {
            base.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error condition where it's not a subtype... perhaps throw an exception if
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to update the other methods that add/update items to the list (index setter, AddRange, Insert, etc)