# Choosing a Subclass without knowing the name of it in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, plugins, module, subclass

Edit 1:If anyone has a better Title for that, feel free to tell me or edit it yourself.
Edit 2: Thanks for your contribution guys, the answer given is almost what I need with some tweaks and I'm thankful for the small stuff here. Really learnt much today!

Little stuff here that I'm banging my head on for a while now.
I want to create a Slideshow and want the logic in the Image objects itself.

The programm should be able to set a desired transition or just a random one so
I wanted to create a Transition Superclass with the general stuff and spezialize
it in the subclasses. So I have Transitions.cs (with no Code currently inside it)
and no derived class. I want it to be in the way of adding a single .cs file
extending Transitions.cs and not change any other code to implement a new Transition.

The Code I currently have looks something like this but I guess my
description is more helpful than the code

```
public class SlideImages : MonoBehaviour {

    Image image;
    Image nextImage;
    int tracker;

    private void Transition(int ID)
    {
        /*Something to choose a transition based on the ID
        *Transitions.cs is the superclass of all different transitions
        *f.e. Ken-Burns Effect, or scattered Transition which all extend from it
        */
    }

    ~SlideImages()
    {
        //TODO: Pop and Push
    }
}
```

I had the idea of something along the lines of static stuff to workaround that
looks like this but it doesn't work I suppose

```
public class Transitions : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int TransitionID;
    protected static int SubclassCount;

    protected static void SetID()
    {
        TransitionID = Transitions.SubclassCount;
        Transitions.SubclassCount++;
    }
}
```

I did look into the state design pattern but I don't want to implement it as I just need the state to be chosen once and shortlived. The Image Objects themself only have a lifetime of around a few seconds. I don't want to do the usual if-nesting or just put all the code inside the SlideImages.cs. Is there any good guidance to it or stuff that goes very indepth into inheritance and such stuff?

Appreciate all the input.

Comment: What about a switch case on a random value which would return a specific transition type depending on the value?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do.  It *sounds* like you want a (potentially abstract) `Transition` type and then a variety of types which inherit from it.  But where is that happening in your code?  Then what do you mean by "choose transition based on id"?  If each image has a `Transition` object (regardless of the implementing type) then can't it just invoke the logic it needs on that object?

Comment: @Isuka There has to be a better way to do it as I have to change the code  manually if I want to insert another transition. Imagine it as a webbased building software. The customer can code his own Transition how he wants it (or any other code in that manner) and just uploads it into a folder. Then everything gets built and its automatically implemented without code changing

Comment: @David Yeah, currently I don't have anything inherited from it because I don't want to code something that doesn't even work. 
The images don't have a `Transition` object but more like a number associated with the derived class. Doesn't have to be the number though, just something to identify a subclass

It somehow has to call the logic from another file which should be part of Transitions.cs as I want to have some similarities and boundaries set in the behaviour

Comment: @Firro: So you need something like a static collection of `Transition` objects, and each image would pull from that collection based on an ID?  If you have a `List<Transition>` then you can simply do: `transitions.Single(t => t.ID == id)` where `transitions` is the list and `id` is the ID you're trying to find in it.

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll have to make myself more knowledgeable about what you just wrote. I think (think in parantheses) that I can't make the classes static as the MonoBehaviour class doesn't allow that, sadly. My colleague just confirmed it as well, but I'll still try something along these lines out and squezze out the potential of it.

Comment: @David Just a small thing, is this kinda helpful if I automate the detection of files in the folder and add them? This looks kinda like what I need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194482/

Comment: @Firro: it sounds like you want a plugin-based system. I've updated my answer with an example of that matching what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two straight-forward solutions to what you want to do. Your basic problem is that you want to be able to dynamically add functionality to your program but you don't want to have knowledge of what has been added in order to use it. The most hack-ish way of doing it is to use `Actions` instead of subclassing. When you want to add another transition you just update an actions list like this:

```
public static class Transitions
{
    private static Action[] TransitionStrategies = new Action[]
    {
        () => { /* One way of performing a transition */ },
        () => { /* Another way of performing a transition */ },
        () => { /* Keep adding methods and calling them here for each transition type */ }
    }

    public static void PerformTransition(int? transitionIndex = null)
    {
        int effectiveIndex;

        // if the transition index is null, use a random one
        if (transitionIndex == null)
        {
            effectiveIndex = new Random().Next(0, TransitionStrategies.Length);
        }
        else
        {
            effectiveIndex = transitionIndex.Value;
        }

        // perform the transition
        TransitionStrategies[effectiveIndex]();

    }
}
```

The above approach is simple but all of the logic (or at least references to the logic depending on where you implement the actual work for the transitions) is in one place. It also has the potential to get quite messy depending on how many transitions you are adding and how many developers are touching this codebase. It also requires all functionality to be added by someone with access to the full codebase and requires a recompilation each time new transitions are added.

A more complex but much more maintainable and flexible approach in the long term is to use modules (or plugins for our purposes). Each transition in that approach is provided by either a shared module or a specific module and is a subclass of a base `AbstractTransition` class or an implementation of an `ITransition` interface depending on how you want to go about doing that. Use post-build tasks to place all of your module dlls in a single directory accessible to your main program (anyone else given permission can put transition module dlls there too). When your program launches, it dynamically loads all dlls from that directory (no recompilation required when new transitions are added as long as the right dlls are in that directory) and pulls out all of the classes implementing that interface. Each of those interface implementations are instantiated and placed into a data structure after which you can use a similar strategy to the above's `PerformTransition` method to perform a random one or one based on an ID instead of an index. I can edit this question with an example of that structure if you would like.

Edit: You didn't ask for it yet, but here's an example with plugins/modules.

First, create a project to load and run the transitions. This example will use a project called `ModuleDemo`. Give it a main method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create a list to hold the transitions we load
    List<AbstractTransition> transitions = new List<AbstractTransition>();

    // load each module we find in the modules directory
    foreach (string dllFilepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles("Modules", "*.dll"))
        // this should really read from the app config to get the module directory                
    {
        Assembly dllAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFilepath);

        transitions.AddRange(dllAssembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(AbstractTransition).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .Select(type => (AbstractTransition) Activator.CreateInstance(type)));
    }

    // show what's been loaded
    foreach (AbstractTransition transition in transitions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded transition with id {0}", transition.TransitionId);

        // execute just to show how it's done
        transition.PerformTransition();
    }

    Console.Read(); // pause
}
```

You'll notice that the method references an `AbstractTransition` class. Let's create a separate `TransitionModule` project for that now. This is the project that the modules will reference:

```
namespace TransitionModule
{
    public abstract class AbstractTransition
    {        
        public readonly int TransitionId;
        public abstract void PerformTransition();

        protected AbstractTransition(int transitionId)
        {
            TransitionId = transitionId;
        }

        // you can add functionality here as you see fit
    }
}
```

Now that we have an abstract transition class for the plugins to implement and a functioning plugin loader, we can go ahead and create a few transition plugins.

I created a `Modules` folder for this in my solution but it doesn't really matter.

First module in a `FlipTransition` project:

```
using System;
using TransitionModule;

namespace FlipTransition
{
    public class FlipTransition : AbstractTransition
    {
        public FlipTransition() : base(2)
        {
        }

        public override void PerformTransition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Performing flip transition");
        }
    }
}
```

Second module in a `SlideTransition` project:

```
using System;
using TransitionModule;

namespace SlideTransition
{
    public class SlideTransition : AbstractTransition
    {
        public SlideTransition() : base(1)
        {
        }

        public override void PerformTransition()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Performing slide transition");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that each of those projects needs to reference the `TransitionModule` project but the main project doesn't need to know about any of the other projects.

Now we have 2 transition plugins and a plugin loader. Since the plugin loader is going to load the modules from a `Modules` directory, go to the `/bin/Debug` directory of the main project and make a `Modules` directory. Copy all of the dlls from the `/bin/Debug` directories of the transition plugin projects into that directory as well. All of this can be automated with post-build tasks later on.

Go ahead and run the program. You should get output like this:

```
Loaded transition with id 2
Performing flip transition
Loaded transition with id 1
Performing slide transition
```

There's a lot you can do to make this more elegant, but this is at least a simple example of how you can use a plugin-based architecture to provide what you need.

Comment: I just came back home, let me read that carefully and I'll come back to that

Comment: By the way, you should probably use `Guid.NewGuid()` to generate the transition ids each module declares instead of integers for ids. That way you can be guaranteed each module registers a unique transition id without having to know what ids are already registered. Use that to generate the id and then hardcode the id into the transition implementation (you might want it to be unchanging between runs so you can store related settings/etc).

Comment: Ok I went over it and its quite hard to get the gist of it. I understand the concept but there are many things (actually nearly everything) that are completely new to me. I'll have to dive into it but yeah, thats kinda what I wanted.

I will need to look into what Assemblys are and such, most stuff that I learnt and like, 95% of courses online are really just basic stuff and these things are actually helpful so I'm really thankful to you.

Comment: If you have any specific questions feel free to post them here or we can continue in chat. If there's anything you'd like me to comment up more I can do that too. Once you get your head around it it's really quite simple and very convenient to develop new transitions for once the framework is in place.

Comment: I can put the example solution on github for you as well if that would make your learning easier.

Comment: nah, its fine like that. Appreciate the intention :) Wish you a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You could try playing around with abstract classes, create a base abstract class for image transitioning;

```
public abstract class ImageTransition
{
    protected int imageId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Image> ImageDictionary { get; set; }

    protected abstract void TransitionToNextImageId();

    public Image GetNextImage()
    {
        TransitionToNextImageId();
        return ImageDictionary[imageId];
    }
}
```

You then create new Transition types that inherit from this base class and have their own implementation of the TransitionToNextImageId method;

```
public class InTurnImageTransition : ImageTransition
{
    protected override void TransitionToNextImageId()
    {
        if(this.imageId < ImageDictionary.Count)
            this.imageId ++;
    }
}

public class RandomImageTransition : ImageTransition
{
    protected override void TransitionToNextImageId()
    {
        imageId = new Random().Next(0, ImageDictionary.Count);
    }
}
```

This allows you to build up some custom transitions however you wish.

**-Edit-**
You would of course fill the dictionary ImageDictionary before calling the GetNextImage method.

Comment: Let me read that carefully, it definitely looks more promising than anything I tried